# React application is not installing on my system

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I not able to install react by `npx create-react-app`. How can I check `node.js` is installed on my system?

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check node by running `node --help`. If it is not installed it will through some error. If you installed but it doesn't give any output for above command, check if it is mapped in the environment variables.